# There are some problems with "console.log"

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/ html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Contact Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

document.write("loading PhoneGap");
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

document.write("PhoneGap loaded");
function onDeviceReady() {
alert("begin");
var myContact = navigator.service.contacts.create({"displayName": "Test User"});
myContact.gender = "male";
document.write("The contact, " + myContact.displayName + ", is of the " + myContact.gender + " gender");
alert("end");
}  

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Example</h1>
 <p>Create Contact</p>
</body>
</ html>
```

The result in the Android's simulator on eclipse is:

loadingPhoneGap PhoneGap loaded
Example
Create Contact

"alert" is missing, it seemed that that function did not work, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the alert function might not be natively supported, can you try using the phonegap alert instead?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
navigator.contacts.create
```

not

```
navigator.service.contacts.create
```

Also, you have a few JavaScript ordering issues. Here is a complete working index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/ html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Contact Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var onDeviceReady = function() {
alert("begin");
var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "Test User"});
myContact.gender = "male";
alert("The contact, " + myContact.displayName + ", is of the " + myContact.gender + " gender");
alert("end");
};

document.write("loading PhoneGap");
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

document.write("PhoneGap loaded");



</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Example</h1>
 <p>Create Contact</p>
</body>
</html>
```